# Is it okay to use MPMoviePlayerController without adding it to our view?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm writing an online radio streaming app. I'm using my own buttons to control the playback. I really don't want the view of MPMoviePlayerController.

Will apple reject my app if I just let it play the audio without adding MPMoviePlayerController to my view?

I'm thinking of removing second last line in the code below:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[player prepareToPlay];

[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];
[myView addSubview: player.view];       //i want to remove this line

[player play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to do the following to hide it without removing that line:

```
player.view.hidden = YES;
```